# Limits of integral series

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, limits-and-convergence

Suppose we have the series of functions:

\begin{equation}
F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)
\end{equation}

where convergence is uniform.

Additionally, consider the partial functions of the series:

\begin{equation}
F_m (x)=\sum_{n=1}^{m} f_n(x)
\end{equation}

Suppose that:

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{F_m(x)}{x^{3}} ,dx
\end{equation}

forms a Cauchy sequence, hence convergent.

Can we then claim that:

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{F_m(x)}{x^{3}} ,dx \to \int_{0}^{1} \frac{F(x)}{x^{3}} ,dx
\end{equation}

as $m \to \infty$?

observation:
\begin{equation}
 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{F(x)}{x^{3}} ,dx
\end{equation}

exist

Comment: What do you mean by "Obs:"?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no with a simple counterxample: consider $G_n(x)=n\chi_{[0,1/n]}(x)$ and $F_n(x)=x^3G_n(x), 0 \le F_n(x) \le 1/n^2$

(so one can define $f_n=F_n-F_{n-1}$)

Then clearly $F_n \to 0$ uniformly and $\int_0^1G_n(x)dx=1 \to 1$, while $F=0$ so $\int_0^1 F(x)dx/x^3=0$

With a little smoothing one clearly can make everything continuous or differentiable as wished etc

Comment: but in this case your sequence of functions is unlimited, if I have a limited sequence?

Comment: what do you mean limited? $F_n/x^3$ bounded?

Comment: no, $F_n(x)$ bounded.

Comment: $F_n$ is bounded by $1/n^2$ in my counterxample, $F_n/x^3$ is unbounded

Answer (score 0):

No.

Indeed, make the substitution $x=u^{-1/2}$. That is, let $G_n(u):=F_n(u^{-1/2})$ and $G(u):=F(u^{-1/2})$, so that $\int_0^1\frac{F_n(x)}{x^3}\,dx=\frac12\,\int_1^\infty G_n$ and $\int_0^1\frac{F(x)}{x^3}\,dx=\frac12\,\int_1^\infty G$.
So, we can
restate the question as follows:

> Let $(G_n)$ be a sequence of functions on $[1,\infty)$ converging uniformly to a function $G$ on $[1,\infty)$ so that $\int_1^\infty G_n$ converges (as $n\to\infty$) and $\int_1^\infty G$ exists. Does it then follow that $\int_1^\infty G_n\to\int_1^\infty G$?

To show that this is not true, let e.g.
$$G_n:=\frac1n\,1_{[n,2n]}.$$
Then $G_n\to0=:G$ uniformly but
$$\int_1^\infty G_n=1\not\to0=\int_1^\infty G.$$

Comment: @georgeandrade : This change of the integrands and of the interval of integration (which results in simpler integrands) is obtained by substitution, as is now explained in detail. Please let me know if further details are needed.

Comment: @georgeandrade : Do you have a further response to the answers on this page?